# Can't make MSDNs simple example c# service

Tags: c#, service

I've attempt to follow MSDN simple make a service instructions

Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
        private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
            eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }


    }
}
```

I seem to fail at the 2nd hurdle, "Adding Features to the Service"

When I compile I get Ambiguity between 'WindowsService1.Service1.eventLog1' and 'WindowsService1.Service1.Service1.eventLog1' and The type 'WindowsService1.Service1' already contains a defintion for 'components'

Comment: Do you already have `components` and `eventLog1` defined in the designer file?

Comment: Seems that you have to variables called eventLog1

Comment: It would appear so but I didn't put them there. Was just blindly following the steps before I understand what a constructor is etc. It seems that as soon as I add the eventlog to the design view it create two entries for components and eventlog1 but the steps do not mention deleting or editting these entries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments people got me looking in the right place, seems that you don't need to do step4 it is done automatically when you add the eventlog in the design view.

```
Service1.designer.cs looks like this

namespace WindowsService4
{
    partial class Service1
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).BeginInit();
            // 
            // Service1
            // 
            this.ServiceName = "Service1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).EndInit();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;
    }
}
```